# How to add/remove claims at any time in controller

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to be able to add/remove claims to users at any time in the applications controllers. How is that possible and what are the steps?

I'm using ASP.NET CORE RC1 and using `Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization`.

for example:

```
public IActionResult ChangeUserInfo(int id, User user)
{
    var mUser = db.Users.Where(d => d.UserId == id).First();
    mUser.Email = user.Email;
    
    // change claims, How?
    
    db.SaveChanges();
    
    return View();
}
```

[I'm using the new Authentication API and **NOT** Identity!](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/)

Edit:

This is a method I made to get the additional claims, add them to claimsidentity and log the user out and then log user in again but it doesn't work. (It works if user manually logs out)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SingInAsync(HttpContext httpContext, string rememberme, bool forceSingOut = false, List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> additionalClaims = null)
        {
            var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("SecureLogin");
            userIdentity.AddClaims(_claims);

            if(additionalClaims != null)
            {
                userIdentity.AddClaims(additionalClaims);
            }

            var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

            if(forceSingOut)
            {
                await httpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookie");
            }

            await httpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", userPrincipal,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = (rememberme != null) ? DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(int.Parse(_config["AppOptions:RememberMeDuration"])) : DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                    IsPersistent = false,
                    AllowRefresh = false,
                });

            return null;
        }
```

and then it's called like:

`await customUserManager.SingInAsync(HttpContext, null, true, additClaims);`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a claim like this

```
public async Task<bool> AddClaim(string type, string value)
    {
        var username = User.GetUserName();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

        Claim claimToAdd = new Claim(type, value);
        var result = await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claimToAdd);

        return result.Succeeded;

    }
```

Deleting claims is very similar, you'd just use _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync instead.

_userManager is an instance of UserManager, which you inject into your controller via dependency injection.

```
 public ClaimController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ClaimController>();
    }
```

Comment: I'm on RC1 and I don't think there is `UserManager` there. Also I'm not using ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: Yes there is.  The namespace is Microsoft.Asp.Net.Identity.UserManager.

Comment: You're wrong. The namespace `Microsoft.Asp.Net` doesn't even exist. There is a `Microsoft.AspNet` though and again I'm NOT using Identity.

Comment: What I'm using is https://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/ and it has nothing to do with Identity.

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, you probably just need to add the proper package from nuget.  But if you don't want to use Identity (which does everything for you...) then presumably you have a UserClaims table in your database that you're accessing using EF, so you'd have to add/remove your claims using EF directly.  db.UserClaims.Add()

Comment: I know that but the problem is not database but the current context that user is already logged in.

Comment: Is that coming from a cookie?  Judging by the source code from the blog you linked you could to get the current claim set using List<Claim> currentClaims = HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList<Claim>();  Then add/remove claims from the list.  Finally, create new ClaimsIdentity with the list of claims and sign the user back in (which will create a new cookie).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing but apparently it doesn't remove the old cookie until user manually logs out and signs in again.

Comment: Have you tried doing a signout for the user using HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync() and then signing them back in?  You could also try Response.Cookies.Delete("nameOfAuthCookie") or overwriting it with an expired version Response.Cookies.Append("nameOfAuthCookie", "", new CookieOptions() { Expires = DateTime.MinValue });

Comment: This isn't really ideal, but you could try doing the logout and then returning a RedirectToAction and in the second action log the user back in.  Not really ideal, but then the logout would remove the cookie, return the result to the browser, who would delete the cookie, and then call the new action to get a new one.  You can use TempData to persist info through a RedirectToAction

Comment: So I tried temp data and it works and is good enough for now.